# Getting Amazon all products via feed API

Tags: php, web-services, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to retrieve all Amazon products via feed with all the details of the products including price and dimensions for each?

I did a bit of research but it seems like Product Advertising API will do the job, but what information is this returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the products based on your search criterion or item look-up criterion.

Each response has one page which has 10 items.

You can get at most 400 pages which means 4000 items. (Even though it may show you the total number of found products Eg: 9000)

So to answer your question, No you cannot get all the products from amazon.  This will basically mean amazon giving up all their database.

Read page 91 http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/